# How do I make a span element slide out from behind an image using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to make a span element slide out (like it's coming from behind an image).

For testing go to http://www.sodrie.be/collectie.html and hover over brand image.

The span element is positioned 'absolute'. When I do relative it doesn't work.

This works perfect in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari. I don't know about IE; I should test it.

**UPDATE 02/03/2011**

The problem is that in Chrome it is working on the first page but when i slide to the second page (arrow on the right). It's not working there!

Comment: @Dante: Could it have to do something with that a SPAN element is `inline`? Try setting `display:block;`

Comment: I'm currently with Chrome and the description slides just fine, what is wrong with Chrome and Safari ?

Comment: Looks the same in Chrome 11, Safari 5, IE7, IE8 as it does in Firefox.

Comment: @Dante, I can confirm that it works on Chrome9, FF3 and IE8 on Win7 What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You don't need to position it relative.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 9.0.597.94 for ubuntu 10.04. But when i'm with my client she has the same problem in Chrome (probably also old version). Seems like coding is OK but it's a version problem. Thanks for your quick replies!

Comment: @Marnix: how can i set it to display:block if I want them to be hidden at the start?

Comment: @JohnP => it's not working on my gf's IE 8.0.6001.18702 but it is working on my work laptop with IE 7.0.5730.13...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem. You haven't paid any attention to the specifications of [`position`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp).

Your site is working quite well and it is also showing your spans, but out of the screen. IE8 even shows a scrollbar when hovering over in the second page.

Solution: You need to set your parents of the span also to a position. Which is something you haven't done yet.

So looking at your structure, you are using LI's to shove around. These are the elements that are moving, so they should be the big position parent. Your structure is like this:

```
<div class="sections"> <!-- make this relative, this is your giant parent -->
    <ul>
        <li> <!-- make these relative, your divs should be bound to this -->
            <div class="item"> <!-- make these relative, so your span can be relative to it -->
                <!-- image here -->
                <span class="info_img"><!-- more --></span> <!-- make this relative, because you want to -->
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You've found it indeed. My span is still positioned absolute, but by positioning its parents relative its working in chrome :). Looks ok! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dante: Yes you can position something absolute inside a relative part as well, but beware that both have different outcomes. Absolute positioning takes your element out of the scope. Read more in the w3schools link about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `position:relative`

http://jsfiddle.net/UeSsu/4/

This should work cross browser.

Comment: Hi, i like your jquery code (much better then mine). But it's not working for me with the position:relative

Comment: @Dante: This code seems to work in IE8 and in IE8 compat-mode (which is IE7 in some way). relative position seems to work fine. Are you also having trouble with this example?

Comment: I'd like to test it in IE6, but don't have that on my machine. I have a feeling that's what is not working.